# PHP causes segmentation fault when executing an mssql_query

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a shell program that loops a PHP script. The PHP script is long and has many includes and defined functions, but one function calls

```
$result_sql = mssql_query($sql);
```

The $sql code is executed in MSSQL query analyzer and runs successfully. The function, when called independently from a small php script works. When adding it to the large script, PHP errors with a segmentation fault. How would one troubleshoot the segmentation fault? PHP usually displays errors encountered when display_errors(); is set to E_NOTICE, but no error description is displayed when PHP segfaults.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: A segmentation fault (aka segfault) is a common condition that causes programs to crash; they are often associated with a file named core . Segfaults are caused by a program trying to read or write an illegal memory location.

Comment: How long is your script? Are you using php5-cli? What's your PHP version? Are you running out of memory in that php script? Is there a timeout on the sql connection to database? Try to reconnect to db before executing that query and see if it works.

Comment: Im using PHP5-cli, yes. It's not too long, maybe 5 files with 200-300 lines of code each, all functions that are called. I am not running out of memory, I set the limit very high and the segfault happens at one specific line of code.

Comment: I implemented a workaround, by passing the requisite values in a JSON string to a shell_exec("php /path/to/file.php '$json_arguments'"); which seems to have worked. The exact block of code in the /path/to/file.php in the position of the master php file causes the segfault. I'm pretty sure I ran into a bug or old version of some library with php.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but launching a mssql stored procedure with PDO statement (statement->prepare / statement->bindParam / statement->execute())

it seems to be a [php bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70565&thanks=6) from the library

must notice though that if i change the stored procedure removing some try/catch and other parts, it works smoothly..

i'll try to split the procedure in few procedures or viceversa (because the original one used to call other SP)
hope to let you know soon